# Is there a function in Mathematica that saves the power of 10 of a number in scientific form?

Tags: number-representation

I have a number for instance `0.0622`.

I want to put it in `ScientificForm` so I do `ScientificForm[0.0622]` obtaining `6.22 x 10^-2`

I want to save the power of `10`, so the `10^-2` can be used to manipulate a list. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: A brute force way is `Log10[6.22 10^-2] // Floor` which gets you -2.

Answer (score 3):

```
decimalExponent[x_] := Floor[Log[10, x]]
decimalExponent[0.0622]
(* -2 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exponent[x_] := Last@RealDigits[x] - 1
```

**Test**

```
t = Table[10^-i, {i, -10, 10}]
exponent /@ t
```

> ```
> {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, \
> -9, -10}
> ```